# Задать правильное условие с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq2sql

Есть БД из одной таблицы, в которой 3 поля: ID, англ слово, перевод.

Для одной из задач я считываю только глаголы с помощью такого выражения(у меня 
все глаголы начинаются с частички "To")

```
words = wordsfromDB.Where(w => w.EnglishWord.StartsWith("To")).ToList();
```

Сейчас я хочу реализовать возможность считывать только фразовые глаголы,
то есть значение "To give" не считается, а значение "To give up" считается.

То есть он должен считывать все записи, которые начинаются на "To" и которые
имеют минимум 3 слова.

Помогите составить верное условие.

Comment: вместо `w.EnglishWord.StartsWith("To")` укажите регулярное выражение. например, `Regex.Match("to\s+\w+\s+up").Success`

Comment: @Stack, регулярные выражения не могут быть транслированы в SQL, это ограничение провайдера linq2sql

Comment: Мне сейчас не важно, я скачиваю все слова в List, а потом добавляю в другой List подходящие мне слова.

Регулярка - это хорошо, но хотелось бы средствами LINQ сделать.

Comment: @Владимир, это вот вы кому отвечали? регулярку как раз и советовали использовать в методе _Where_, например если вызывать его после _ToList_

Comment: Теперь понял, что регулярку запихнуть в условие.

Comment: либо так же проверить, что три слова, например, `w.EnglishWord.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length > 2` и это тоже в `Where` после _ToList_

Comment: @Владимир, база данных в SQL Server'e?

Comment: Да, там находится

Comment: Всё, я написал себе такое выражение для считывания фразовых глаголов:

' words = wordsfromDB.Where(w => w.EnglishWord.Split().Length > 2).ToList().Where(w => w.EnglishWord.StartsWith("To ")).ToList(); '

Comment: @Владимир, во первых, не надо на каждом "чихе" приводить результат Linq выражения (IEnumirable) к List и во вторых, Ваше решение очень плохое, оно будет загружать все данные из таблицы, какие там будут, и будет на клиенте разбивать их на под строки и искать нужные. Так делать не рационально. Прислушайтесь к ответу Stack.

Answer (score 4):

Не используйте регулярные выражения без особой на то необходимости. Как в чистом SQL, так и в "LINQ to SQL", для подобных запросов существует оператор `LIKE`, тоже позволяющий выполнять отбор по текстовым шаблонам:

```
words = wordsfromDB.Where(w => SqlMethods.Like(w.EnglishWord, "To % up")).ToList();
```

Выполняется он на порядок быстрее несвойственных для SQL "костылей" с регулярными выражениями.

А вообще, по задаче - посмотрите на полнотекстовый поиск. Там как расширенные текстовые запросы, так и граматическо-словарные ядра, причем не только для английского.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь то _up_ это только для примера и в выражении вместо него наверное тоже стоит `%` поставить `SqlMethods.Like(w.EnglishWord, "To % %")` так как не важно какие три слова.

Comment: @Grundy, возможно. Но точную формулировку задачи знает только автор. Я просто взял регулярное выражение из первого комментария к вопросу, да преобразовал её в текстовый шаблон для использования в LIKE/PATINDEX. Больше для примера, как иллюстрация того, что здесь можно обойтись стандартными для SQL средствами.

Comment: Просто в самом посте указано: _все записи, которые начинаются на "To" и которые имеют минимум 3 слова._

Comment: Я потом у себя уже исправил и выше написал через LINQ:
все записи, которые начинаются на "To ", то есть с пробелом, и минимум 3 слова.
И в мою выборку попадают только фразовые глаголы.

Comment: У меня работает такой вариант:
words = wordsfromDB.Where(w => w.EnglishWord.Split().Length > 2).ToList().Where(w => w.EnglishWord.StartsWith("To ")).ToList();

        А вот такой вариант не работает: (using я добавил)
words = wordsfromDB.Where(w => SqlMethods.Like(w.EnglishWord, "To % %")).ToList();

Ошибка выдаётся такая: Не удаётся использовать метод Like на клиенте. Он предназначен только для преобразования в SQL

Comment: @Владимир, значит вы работаете вовсе не с базой данных, а скажем тупо `List<>`, выгруженный ранее. Инициализацию `wordsfromDB` вы в вопросе не показали, поэтому учитывая заголовок и теги, все решили что это ссылка на настоящий `DbSet<>`, работающий с базой данных.

Comment: @Владимир, вам нужно было использовать условия выборки из базы перед тем, как зачем-то на клиенте преобразовывайте `DbSet<>` в `List<>` в каком-то куске кода, который в показанный вами пример не попал.

Answer (score 0):

Если база данных будет расти, то вместо того, чтобы загружать данные в приложение для последующей обработки, можно выполнять обработку на сервере.
В SQL Server есть CLR, и можно определить UDF (user defined function) на C#.
UDF выполняется на сервере.  Описание и примеры - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx).

---

UPDATE:

Если в базе данных хранятся отдельные предложения, а для выборки предложений не подходит LIKE, то наверное, надо пересмотреть структуру данных и хранить отдельные слова с идентификатором предложения.

Comment: То есть выборка будет осуществляться в самой БД, а в моё приложение сразу загрузятся не все слова, а только те, которые подходили по условию. Верно ?

Comment: да,  вся обработка (и на основе regex) будет в sql server, а в приложение загрузится только отфильтрованный результат.

Comment: Тут экономия только в трафике между приложением и сервером. В остальном - просто перекладывание ответственности "с больной головы на здоровую". Если клиентское приложение и сервер СУБДД расположены близко в сети, либо вообще на одном сервере/компьютере, то польза будет нулевая. А если сервером СУБДД пользуется более одного клиентского приложения - посадка в производительности распределится на всех.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov если база данных небольшая и нужна только для выборки данных, то ее можно и целиком копировать (раньше, если не ошибаюсь, это называли клиент-серверная архитектура), но у такого решения много минусов, включая нарушение srp (single responsibility principle).

Comment: @Stack, Ваше решение фактически сводится к перебору всех строк таблицы и применением к каждой из них CLR-функции - это медленного. Анализировать код ваших CLR-функции, и оптимизировать их логику для использования индексов и натурального порядка элементов, к сожалению, SQL Server пока не умеет, и вряд ли когда-либо научится. Если хотите использовать своё решение на клиенте, и "не нарушать SRP"(в скобках, т.к. на самом деле мы не можем судить сейчас об ответственностях маленького кусочка кода, данного автором) - тупо скопируйте CLR-UDF-ку в проект, снеся аннотацию "SqlFunction" над методом.

Comment: @Stack, и да, ваше решение не доступно в СУБД, отличных от SQL Server. Моё же решение(с использованием оператора `LIKE`) - быстрее(за счет использования индексов и натурального порядка), и является частью стандарта SQL(соответственно доступно независимо от используемой СУБДД - в SQL Server, Oracle RDBMS, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, и т.д.)

Comment: @Stack, и да, "копирование баз данных целиком с сервера на клиент" - это вовсе не то,  что  "называли клиент-серверная архитектура" :)) Клиент-серверная архитектура - это когда есть один сервер, и к нему могут подключатся несколько клиентов, для выполнения каких-то задач или получения данных. Её широко используют и в данный момент времени, и никуда она не денется ещё много-много лет. Альтернативой ей является только архитектура одноранговых сетей(p2p) - там нет централизованности, и каждый участник является одновременно и клиентом и сервером. :)

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"Ваше решение фактически сводится к перебору всех строк таблицы и применением к каждой из них CLR-функции - это медленного."_ -- медленно или нет надо смотреть профайлером и т.д.. Но как бы ни было, если требуется использовать Regex, то лучше выборку делать на сервере, чем загружать таблицу на клиента и делать тот же перебор на нем. А вообще, лучше пересмотреть структуру данных. Например, хранить не предложения, а отдельные слова и номера предложений. В таком случае можно будет использовать LIKE.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"клиент-серверная архитектура" :))"_ -- из моего поста же понятно, что я говорю о файл-серверной архитектуре, когда файлы копируются целиком на клиента, как вы и предлагали [выше](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476412/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-linq/476427?noredirect=1#comment541683_476427).

Comment: @Stack, из моего комментария же понятно, что я сравниваю ваше [предыдущее решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476412/17298#comment-541567) c вашим же его [текущим вариантом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476427/17298) :)

Comment: @Stack, а вот и посмотрите профайлером ;) В случаях "что-то как бы надо как-то сделать" - вначале уточняют задачу и смотрят на неё целиком, и только потом предлагают решения. Далее оценивают плюсы/минусы конкретных решений, выбирая наиболее приемлемое. Нельзя в программировании для абсолютно всех ситуаций сказать "все-все-все! делайте только вооот так!". :)

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"Далее оценивают плюсы/минусы конкретных решений"_ -- задача дана в вопросе. LIKE - это хорошо известное решение. в добавок я предложил использовать Regex, и малоизвестное решение на основе CLR UDF, т.к. автор вопроса сказал что используется SQL Server. а оценивать решение мы не можем, т.к. не знаем всех обстоятельств.

Comment: @Stack, а теперь маааленький шок: `wordsfromDB` - это вовсе не `DbSet<>`, т.к. оказалось что [работа происходит вовсе не с базой данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476412/17298#comment-542244). Оба наши решения в корне не верны. XD

Comment: @SergeyRufanov решения верны, просто они не подходят автору вопроса. как я и говорил, мы не знаем всех условий задачи.

Comment: @Stack, ну да, они верны, но далеко не для конкретно этой задачи )